# Can't ParseDouble on some devices

Tags: java, android

i'm using a `NumberTextWatcher` for realtime-edit for an `EditText` and it's working fine for me, 
but some users reporting that they got `NumberException` problem, i think this is because numbers changes in 123,456 in `EditText` and cant parse to doubles, so i did some change and use `Replace("," , "")` code but this is not working for some too!
what should i do so this code works for all of my users?
Thanks and Sorry for my Poor English :D

*NumberTextWatcher*:

```
public NumberTextWatcher(EditText et)
{
    df = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    df.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
    dfnd = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    this.et = et;
    hasFractionalPart = false;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final String TAG = "NumberTextWatcher";

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
    et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    try {
        int inilen, endlen;
        inilen = et.getText().length();

        String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
        Number n = df.parse(v);
        int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
        if (hasFractionalPart) {
            et.setText(df.format(n));
        } else {
            et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
        }
        endlen = et.getText().length();
        int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
        if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
            et.setSelection(sel);
        } else {
            // place cursor at the end?
            et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // do nothing?
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // do nothing?
    }

    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
{
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
{
    if (s.toString().contains(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getDecimalSeparator())))
    {
        hasFractionalPart = true;
    } else {
        hasFractionalPart = false;
    }
}
```

And Here is *MainActivity*:

```
final EditText amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final EditText duration = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
final EditText interest = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
amount.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(amount));
duration.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(duration));
interest.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(interest));
String amount1 = amount.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", "");
String duration1 = duration.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", "");
String interest1 = interest.getText().toString().replaceAll(",", "");
try{
double i = Double.parseDouble(amount1);
double j = Double.parseDouble(duration1);
double z = Double.parseDouble(interest1);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){

 }
```

Comment: Can't ParseDouble on some devices?? Really?? This is not device dependent.

Comment: Yes! this code is working fine on my LG G2, but i get reports that it's not working on some devices like Galaxy S4 or Xperia Z1

Comment: It won't be the double parsing. It will be the value which is fed into the parser. Or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Programs store and operate on numbers in a locale-independent way. Before displaying or printing a number, a program must convert it to a String that is in a locale-sensitive format. For example, in France the number 123456.78 should be formatted as 123 456,78, and in Germany it should appear as 123.456,78. So you can't just replace "," and ".".

The following code is an example on how to convert from double and back using the current currency of a user in the United States.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Currency;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault();
        Currency currentCurrency = Currency.getInstance(currentLocale);
        Double currencyAmount = new Double(9876543.21);
        NumberFormat currencyFormatter = 
                NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(currentLocale);
        System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(currentLocale));
        System.out.println(
                           currentLocale.getDisplayName() + ", " +
                           currentCurrency.getDisplayName() + ": " +
                           currencyFormatter.format(currencyAmount));

        try
        {
            System.out.println(currencyFormatter.parseObject("$9,876,543.21"));
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What else could you do:
* make sure users are entering properly formatted numbers. For example, you should not see any other chars except numbers , . + - $, etc.
* IF you know the user will ALWAYS enter two decimal digits, for example, 10 dollars would be expressed as 10.00 (or 10,00), then you can safely remove all "," and "." and get the original number by dividing it by 100, but remember to also remove spaces (remember France :) )

Also, check the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that other users might be inputting ill-formatted numbers. So you are just replacing the commas with white spaces. Maybe you should replace all non-digit characters?

```
amount1 = amount.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
```

Or if you want them to leave the decimal points then use the following:

```
amount1 = amount.getText().toString().replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
```